# Should I use one or two commas in this sentence?

Tags: commas, names

can you please advise whether there are two commas: "videos, led by our Head Coach, Henry" OR only before the name? Can you please explain why?

Full-sentence:

> In the upcoming weeks, we are excited to share with you some useful tennis coaching videos, led by our Head Coach, Henry.

Comment: Your tense is wrong, Teresa.  You need to use a future tense.  Try something like, *In the upcoming weeks, we **will be/are going to be** excited to share...*

Answer (score -1):

That is going to depend on what style-guide you are following, I think. The first comma is distinctly optional in my view, but others will probably disagree with me, both for and against its presence.

Same goes for the first comma in the full sentence - when spoken out-loud there would be no pause there, and it isn't being used to separate a list, but does make it easier to read, by "chunking" the phrases.

Although the last comma is also a little controversial, could just as easily be a colon or a dash!

Comment: Really? When following a job title with the holder's name, I wouldn't expect to see anything 'stronger' than a comma.

Comment: @KateBunting  My professional writing is all technical, to some degree, so maybe more formal than you are used to? I did say that "others will probably disagree" !

Comment: "The Chairman, Mr. Brown" seems normal to me at any level of formality.

Comment: "The Chairman: Mr. Brown" seems more sensible to me.